# Bootstrap Datepicker на angular выбирает на день назад

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs, datepicker

Есть страница с angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js. На ней находится 2 datepicker для выбора периода(начало и конец).

```
            <body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="container" id="page"  style="padding-top: 60px;"  ng-controller="MyController">  
    Дата начала периода <input datepicker-local-date  type="text" data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" data-ng-model="dateFrom">
                Дата окончания периода <input datepicker-local-date  type="text"  data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" data-ng-model="dateTo">
```

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker', 'angular.filter']);
function MyController($scope, $http, $filter){
                     $scope.datepickerOptions = {
                                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                language: 'ru',
                                autoclose: true,
                                weekStart: 1
                            };};
```

`

Проблема заключается в том, что при выборе даты, дата устанавливается на день раньше. т.е. Если я нажимаю в выподающем календаре 1.08.2015, то дата устанавливается на 31.07.2015. Думал проблема в тайм зоне [пример решения](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2072), но это не помогло. Пошагово исследовал эту директиво и оказалось, что дата приходит туда уже на день меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, проблема в том, что Вы не инициализируете `dateTo` и `dateFrom`.
Исправил, теперь дата выставляется верно, посмотрите, пожалуйста http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/7/

Comment: У меня в вашем примере такая же реакция на изменение даты, т.е я ставлю на 2015-10-21, а становится, после исчезновения календаря 2015-10-20